# How can I load a specific area of a file into a Property - Java

Tags: java, file-io, properties-file

What I already have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    Properties prop2 = new Properties();

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file1");
    InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream("file2");

    prop.load(is);
    prop2.load(is2);

    }
}
```

This loads me the whole file1 and the whole file2 into prop and prop2.
The whole file1 into prop is what I want but I only want to load a specific area of file2 into prop2. The area always starts with "[groups]" and always ends with "[".
Both files are full of "team1 = user1, user2, user3" next line "team2 = user4, user 5, user 6" next line. But in file 2 there are also other things which I don't need. I only need the section which is written between the keyword "[groups]" and "[" 
Can anyone help me how to realize it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please paste the format/snippet of the file here?

Comment: You can open file read line by line and search for start pattern, once you find "start pattern" keep storing subsequent line in StringBuilder or another file until you find end pattern in any line.

Comment: Both files are full of "team1 = user1, user2, user3" next line "team2 = user4, user 5, user 6" next line. But in file 2 there are also other things which I don't need. I only need the section which is written between the keyword "[groups]" and "["

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing is to convert your file contents into `StringBuilder` and then `subString` that start with `[groups]` and end with `[`. Your code may look like this;

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
Properties prop2 = new Properties();

InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file1");      
InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream("file2");

StringBuilder fileData= convertToString(is2);
int start = fileData.indexOf("[groups]");
int end = fileData.indexOf("[", start + 8) + 1;

InputStream file2Section = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData.substring(start, end).toString().getBytes());

prop.load(is);
prop2.load(file2Section);
```

You can use the below helper method to convert `InputStream` to `StringBuilder` for `subString` function.

```
private StringBuilder convertToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))) {
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            textBuilder.append((char) c);
        }
    }
    return textBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Hey fabfas, first thank you a lot for your time. Your code does work how expected but doesent work with my scenario because "fileData.lastIndexOf("[") + 1"  finds the last "[" of the document. I need to use the first one after the kyword "[groups]". Any idea which one to use instead of "lastIndexOf"?

Comment: In that case, you should use `indexOf("[", start + 8)`. It will returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index. I have changed the method.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I don't understand everything what you did, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

The [Properties API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) doesn't provide such a feature.
As workaround, stream the Properties and filter entries that match your condition :

```
prop2 = prop2.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(e -> {
                     String key = e.getKey()
                                   .toString();
                     return key.startsWith("[groups]") && key.endsWith("]");
                 })
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> {
                     throw new RuntimeException("dup key");
                 }, Properties::new));
```

But if your file is huge, this should be fine.

I specified in the `mergeFunction`  to throw `RuntimeException` if a key has duplicate values (it may be a desirable check) but you may choose another behavior if it makes sense.